# VSTS 2012 Load/Web Test: Transactions not showing up in the tables tab (Empty table)

Tags: load-testing, visualstudio

I just ran a test for around 150 users for almost over an hour. After the test I find that the transaction response times are not generated in the Tables tab. I can however notice them on the summary page.

How do I retrieve the results with all the transactions' response times?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if the table is empty then the data for that table is unlike to be recoverable. You could look in the database and see if [one of the tables](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/slumley/2010/02/12/description-of-tables-and-columns-in-vs-2010-load-test-database/) has the data.

The transaction table will only contain data if the tests have transactions. Note that Visual Studio Web Performance tests have a very specific meaning for "transaction". They can be added by the context (right click) menu in the ".webtest" editor.

When a test is aborted I have found that several tables may be incomplete.